# Demonstrate a discrepancy?

Tags: idioms

I was writing some article about scientific debate over one subject and then came to my keyboard the following : "... demonstrate large variability..." .

I was wondering if I could replace *variability* with *discrepancies*, sounding a bit more elaborate ? In other words, it is idiomatic ?

*Edit: There seems to be needed a clarification of the problem/debate in order to determine correct wording. It is about a property of biologic tissue, where authors have used a lot of values in their studies, while there should only be one.*

Comment: The two words are not synonymous, so which you use depends on what idea you're trying to express. If you [edit] your question to include that detail (as as many more as are relevant), we can offer more specific guidance. Absent that, the only answer we can provide is "it's up to you".

Comment: "discrepancy" means "a difference between what is stated and what is  actually there", and so it's only synonymous with "variability" in a context where it has been stated that no such variability exists.

Comment: Do you mean "identify", "highlight" or "display" ? Is it "discrepancies", "variability" or "abnormalities" ?

Comment: the problem is about large panel of values used to describe only one property. I guess there are discrepancies over which value you should use, but there is also variability because there are a lot of suggested values.

Comment: @Blue_Elephant There can't be "discrepancies" over "which value to use"; maybe you mean *disagreement*? I'd recommend opening whatever dictionary you offer and scanning the definition of *discrepancy*, it doesn't mean what you seem to think it means.

Comment: What about "show/exhibit a wide range of variation" ?

Comment: @DanBron I took Cambridge online dictionary, here's what I've got: _**a ​difference between two things that should be the same**_ . Looking for disagreement: _**an ​argument or a ​situation in which ​people do not have the same ​opinion**_ So I guess the property should indeed be unique, but is not, that's for discrepancies, and authors also disagree on which value the property should take, which also lead to a disagreement. So there can be both ?

Comment: @Blue_Elephant The key discrepancy () in your understanding is the "should be the same". A *discrepancy* is something which diverges from the *correct*, *proper*, *factual*, *established*, or *agreed-upon*: but in your scenario there are differences of opinion, so there *is no* agreed-upon or established "correct" choice. In other words: there is no "discrepancy" because there is no (unique) "should". Each of the differing opinions is a separate "should" (Bob says we "should" use value X, Jane says we "should" use value Z, etc). You need facts or consensus before you can have discrepancies.

Comment: @DanBron Too bad I cannot validate a comment !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Discrepancy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discrepancies) is a lack of compatibility or similarity between two or more facts.

> Divergence or disagreement, as between facts or claims; difference... A [discrepancy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/difference) is a difference between things that **should correspond or match**: a *discrepancy* between his words and his actions.

A synonym for *discrepancy* is *difference*, not variability. Difference is the most general of the *various* words used as synonyms for *types of differences.*

> With laughter, and with more than one slap of his hand on my shoulder that was more caress than jollity, he pointed out the *discrepancies* in my tale... - Jack London

[Variance](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/variance) is an amount of difference or change

> the state, quality, or fact of being variable, divergent, different, or anomalous.

Leaves vary in shape, color and size. There is a lot of variation in leaf shapes, color and size, but no discrepancies. If someone claimed that maple leaves were ovate (instead of palmate), that would be a discrepancy from the truth. If one person described the same leaf as ovate, and one as palmate, there would exist a discrepancy between them.

If Jack London told his tale *differently* each time, the differences between the tales would be variations, not discrepancies, unless he was claiming each variation was the true version.

Comment: That was a fine nuance that is very well explained here. Thank you !